# Exercise with differential linear equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, determinant

I need to do this exercise but i can't find the solution, i have tryed to substitute $\phi_1(t)$, $\phi_2(t)$ with their solution of the differential equation when the delta is positive but i was wondering if there is a method for solve this without sostitution and for general case.

we have $y''+by'+cy=0$ a differential linear equation with $b, c \in C(I)$, $ I\subset R $, $I$ interval

$W(t)=det\begin{bmatrix}\phi_1(t) & \phi_2(t)\\\phi_1'(t) & \phi_2'(t)\end{bmatrix}$ where $\phi_1(t)$, $\phi_2(t)$ $\in V_2$ 
($\phi_1(t)$, $\phi_2(t)$) are solutions for $y''+by'+cy=0$)

Proof that W satisfy this differential equation:

$W'=-bW$

Proof that {$\phi_1(t)$, $\phi_2(t)$} is a base for $V_2$ if and only if exist $t\in I$ such that $W(t)\ne 0$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Starting from:
$$W(t)=\begin{vmatrix}\phi_1(t) & \phi_2(t)\\\phi_1'(t) & \phi_2'(t)\end{vmatrix}$$
Differentiate the determinant:
$$W'(t)=\begin{vmatrix}\phi_1'(t) & \phi_2'(t)\\\phi_1'(t) & \phi_2'(t)\end{vmatrix}+\begin{vmatrix}\phi_1(t) & \phi_2(t)\\\phi_1''(t) & \phi_2''(t)\end{vmatrix}$$
Since the first determinant is zero, we have:
$$ \implies W'(t)=\begin{vmatrix}\phi_1(t) & \phi_2(t)\\\phi_1''(t) & \phi_2''(t)\end{vmatrix}$$
Now check that you have:
$$\begin{vmatrix}\phi_1(t) & \phi_2(t)\\\phi_1''(t) & \phi_2''(t)\end{vmatrix}=-b\begin{vmatrix}\phi_1(t) & \phi_2(t)\\\phi_1'(t) & \phi_2'(t)\end{vmatrix}$$
$$\phi_2''(t)\phi_1(t)+b\phi_2'(t)\phi_1(t)=\phi_1''(t)\phi_2(t)+b\phi_1'(t)\phi_2(t)$$
$$\phi_1(t)(\phi_2''(t)+b\phi_2'(t))=\phi_2(t)(\phi_1''(t)+b\phi_1'(t))$$
Using the DE:
$$
\begin{cases}
\phi_2''(t)+b\phi_2'(t)+c\phi_2(t)=0 \\
\phi_1''(t)+b\phi_1'(t)+c\phi_1(t)=0
\end{cases}
$$
It gives us:
$$\phi_1(t)(-c\phi_2(t))=\phi_2(t)(-c\phi_1)$$
Which is true.

Comment: And do you know how to:
Proof that {ϕ1(t), ϕ2(t)} is a base for V2 if and only if exist t∈I such that W(t)≠0 ?

Comment: @DanieleTr I didn't see that question. You have to think about linear independance...Just google it.